# cURL - Transfering form fine, however can't get the variables from the other server

Tags: php, curl, cross-server

The title might be a bit misleading but I am unsure how to formulate it in an other way.

I am sending variables cross server using the following script:

```
<?php

     if($_POST) {
        $ch = curl_init("http://jecom.nl/bank/mods/jecom/jecom.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                    array('description' => $_POST['description'], 'amount' => $_POST['amount'], 'receiver'=> $_POST['receiver']));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); 
        // set to false if you want to see what redirect header was sent       
        // snippet 1
        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);
    }                           
?>
```

This works, and I get the variables to `jecom.php` on the other server.

This is the receiving page:

```
<?php

require_once 'jecom_req.php'; //Basic requirements file

$receiver = ($_POST["receiver"]);
$amount = ($_POST["amount"]);
$description = ($_POST["description"]);
$sender = $_SESSION['username']; //their username.
$balance = get_funds($sender, $server);
?>


<h1>Confirm payment</h1>
<p>Please be carefull to confirm your payment to the other party. All transactions are logged to prevent fraud.</p>

<form name="confirmation" method="post" action="jecom_send.php">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Your account name:</td>
    <td><?php echo $sender; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Current Balance:</td>
    <td><?php echo $balance; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Receiving party:</td>
    <td><?php echo $receiver; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description:</td>
    <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Amount:</td>
    <td><?php echo $amount; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">I hereby confirm this information is correct and want to transfer the money.</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="receiver" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $receiver; ?>" />
<input name="description" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
<input name="confirmation" type="hidden" value="http://jecom.nl/bank/mods/jecom/confirmation.php" />
</form>
```

I'm getting the values from the form (as expected) but not `$sender` and `$balance`, also when I press submit it doesn't send them to the correct page but expects to find `jecom_find.php` on the form server. Now this doesn't surprise me and I thought of the followlocation but at the moment this doesn't work (`openbase_dir` and `safe_mode` are still one). Is it possible to go around this or not?

Answer (score 0):

If its cross-server the $_SESSION variable wont be set on the second server. So it will always be null, and so, you will never get the balance as your calling

```
$balance = get_funds( NULL , $server);
```

Comment: How do we know get_funds doesn't use json data?

Comment: It could be. But without his variables being set, it doesn't really matter.